# How to override CSS

Tags: css, primefaces

I have basic CSS experienced so I would like to know how can I remove a style CSS that was set by Primefaces?

```
.ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-content .ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-header .ui-inputfield {
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px #74B2E2 inset;
}
```

I created my own stylesheet myCustomStyle.css

```
.ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-content .ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-header .ui-inputfield {
    box-shadow: ?????? (How can I override the styling)
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Use `box-shadow:none` to reset the `box-shadow` to the defaults.

See [this source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/box-shadow) for information about the `box-shadow` property. All properties can be "resetted" by defining the same property, and using the default value.

To get your `myCustomStyle.css` override the Primefaces' css file, you have to include your custom file *after* the primefaces' file.

A **last** resort: If your custom style doesn't get applied, add `!important` after your declaration (but before the semicolon): `box-shadow: none !important`

Comment: **where is primefaces theme css including?** i need to know to locate my custom style after it. thanks

Comment: According to the [User's guide](http://primefaces.googlecode.com/files/primefaces_users_guide_3_0_RC2.pdf) from the [PrimeFaces documentation](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation.html), page 414, the CSS file has to be placed in a JAR file, at: `/META-INF/resources/<theme name>/theme.css`. Have a look at the linked PDF file (12Mb) at this comment.

Comment: sorry i wasnt clear. what i want to ask is not the place of theme.css, with which line in the code we included it in the project, where is the <link stylesheet etc> i searched my project but could not find

Comment: Ah, I'd never understood how !important works! Now I see! thanks!

Answer (score 3):

```
.ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-content .ui-inputfield, .ui-widget-header .ui-inputfield {
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

There's a whole issue of precedence here too, but if you're style sheet is inserted after the other one, then it will normally work. If it doesn't, add `!important` after the `none`.

Answer (score 0):

I would like to add that the Primefaces framework utilizes prebuilt themes using the [jQuery UI ThemeRoller](http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/).

You can use the ThemeRoller to create new themes or modify existing themes to your liking.