# Tiny Mce Iframe body background-color

Tags: tinymce

Is it possible to chnage tiny-mce body bg-color of iframe body. i am unable to change it becoz tiny-mce-min.css comes from cdn so how to overwrite it or it can be possible to load it locally.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to override CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7646476/how-to-override-css)

Comment: This may be related to TinyMCE API specifically: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1414332/2715716

Comment: but not getting how to change text color of editor. please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I'm probably late to the party, but you can achieve this by appending styles to the iframe.

```js
let iframe = document.querySelector('fieldset iframe');// or use iframe id something like "selector_ifr"
  let style = document.createElement('style');
  style.textContent =
  `
    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Manrope:wght@400;600;700&display=swap');
    body {
      background: #17191B !important;
      font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif !important;
      color: #81729A !important;
      transition: all .25s !important;
    }
    body:focus-visible {
      background: #0E0C12 !important;
    }
  `;
  iframe.contentDocument.head.appendChild(style);
```

Please note, this is an ugly hack.